# Is the anti-forgery token for logout necessary?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

For all my site pages, after being logged in for a few minutes, i get the following error when I attempt to log out:

> The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.

I read in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766975/requestverificationtoken-does-not-match/7871772#7871772) about ways to track this exception down, but since this exception only appears on logout, I wonder if it might just be easier exclude the anti-forgery-token for the logout form altogether. Is that a good idea?

I am using the template login page that is auto-generated with new MVC projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is advisable to add the token to a logout form, otherwise someone can create a page that posts to your logout page, logging out your users, which is annoying.