# The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()...
```

and action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl, string City)
{
}
```

occasionally (once a week), I get the error:

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is
>   hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running
>   the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the configuration
>   specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

i try add to webconfig:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"  
    decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />
```

but the error still appears occasionally

I noticed this error occurs, for example when a person came from one computer and then trying another computer

Or sometimes an auto value set with incorrect data type like bool to integer to the form field by any jQuery code please also check it.

Comment: AutoGenerate will not create the same key on all machines.  I'm confused why you said it can't be used, then you tried to use it.

Comment: and specify it (the encryption key) specifically - can please show example

Comment: Wouldn't "AutoGenerate" generate a new key when your application pool reloads, causing this issue when a form from an older w3wp.exe is handled by a newer w3wp.exe?

Comment: I got this error When i am Open Login Window Long Time, Then Try to Login Got this error. Just Reload this Login Window and Try to Login will Solve the Problem. But I Don't Know How to FIx

Answer (score 151):

I just received this error as well and, in my case, it was caused by the anti-forgery token being applied twice in the same form. The second instance was coming from a partial view so wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: How can I tell if this is happening to me, and how do I fix it?

Comment: By commenting out the AntiForgery token in my partial view, I stopped getting the error. The problem is now if that partial view is used on several different pages, I don't know when to apply the AntiForgery token.

Comment: Can't you just apply the token when you initialise each form or is your solution more complex than that?

Comment: I was also getting this error due to more than one anti-forgery token on the page (Log Off is wrapped by form element in MVC default template) but, I was doing ajax postback. Then I realised I was calling $('form').serialize() and changed that to $('#my-form-id').serialize().

Comment: I know this was over a year ago, but do you recall if this was immediately obvious @SteveDowling? Today, we've been getting a tremendous amount of calls from clients reporting this "key cannot be decrypted" error. We believe it's because of multiple calls to `@Html.AntiforgeryToken()` from different partials, but it's weird that it hasn't been an issue for *months* and then suddenly we're getting bombarded with complaints...

Comment: I haven't touched this for ages but, from memory, I don't think it was obvious at all. It took a bit a of hacking to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Can someone clarify this for me please? One of the sites I've developed has this issue, and I'm going to try and track down the rogue AntiForgeryToken, but I'm not sure if the issue is with one **form** containing two tokens, or one **page** containing two tokens. Which is it?

Comment: I think it is fine for the page to have two tokens as long as only one is being passed to the form. Check the generated HTML source and make sure each form on the page only has one hidden field containing an anti-forgery token. Search for __RequestVerificationToken in the generated page source.

Comment: I checked all the forms on the page yesterday and couldn't find any issues - each one had only a single token. When I came in today and checked again, both instances of the site which were displaying this error are working correctly. Is it possible IIS or some worker processes had somehow screwed up? Literally nothing has changed in the code overnight.

Comment: It Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 35):

**validationKey="AutoGenerate"**

This tells ASP.NET to generate a new encryption key for use in encrypting things like authentication tickets and antiforgery tokens every time the application starts up. If you received a request that used a different key (prior to a restart for instance) to encrypt items of the request (e.g. authenication cookies) that this exception can occur.

If you move away from "AutoGenerate" and specify it (the encryption key) specifically, requests that depend on that key to be decrypted correctly and validation will work from app restart to restart. For example:

```
<machineKey  
validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7
               AD972A119482D15A4127461DB1DC347C1A63AE5F1CCFAACFF1B72A7F0A281B"           
decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

You can read to your heart's content at MSDN page: [How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx)

Comment: and specify it (the encryption key) specifically - can please show example.   like validationKey="sdasdf34234defsdf+*-"
                    decryptionKey="sdasdf34234defsdf+*-"   and its key will be for all my users?

Comment: Yes, this is how requests are validated in webfarm scenarios. HTH

Comment: I believe this is happening to me. I deploy often, and even during high-traffic times, and it seems this only occurs on app restarts/deployments.

Comment: Having machine id will make things complicated when we move on to new servers. When we move on to new servers, someone should consciously update the web.config file is there another option that we can try

Answer (score 19):

Just generate `<machineKey .../>` tag from [a link](http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx) for your framework version and insert into `<system.web><system.web/>` in Web.config if it does not exist.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know M$ gives the code to generate the keys.. but that link just makes life much easier. Thanks for giving location and a quick way to fix this. If mark this as the answer if it was my question :P

Comment: Having machine id will make things complicated when we move on to new servers. When we move on to new servers, someone should consciously update the web.config file is there another option that we can try

Answer (score 18):

If you get here from google for your own developer machine showing this error, try to clear cookies in the browser. Clear Browser cookies worked for me.

Comment: Worked out for me, even in production

Answer (score 8):

in **asp.net Core** you should set Data Protection system.I test in Asp.Net Core 2.1 or higher.

there are multi way to do this and you can find more information at [Configure Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview) and [Replace the ASP.NET machineKey in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey) and [key storage providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers).

- **first way:** Local file (easy implementation)

  **startup.cs** content:

  ```
  public class Startup
  {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
     {
         Configuration = configuration;
         WebHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
     public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }

     // This method gets called by the runtime.
     // Use this method to add services to the container.
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         // .... Add your services like :
         // services.AddControllersWithViews();
         // services.AddRazorPages();

         // ----- finally Add this DataProtection -----
         var keysFolder = Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "temp-keys");
         services.AddDataProtection()
             .SetApplicationName("Your_Project_Name")
             .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysFolder))
             .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
     }
  }
  ```
- **second way:** save to db

  The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore` [NuGet
  package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore/) must be added to the project file

  Add `MyKeysConnection` ConnectionString to your projects
  ConnectionStrings in `appsettings.json > ConnectionStrings >
  MyKeysConnection`.

  Add `MyKeysContext` class to your project.

  **MyKeysContext.cs** content:

  ```
  public class MyKeysContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
  {
     // A recommended constructor overload when using EF Core 
     // with dependency injection.
     public MyKeysContext(DbContextOptions<MyKeysContext> options) 
         : base(options) { }

     // This maps to the table that stores keys.
     public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  **startup.cs** content:

  ```
  public class Startup
  {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         Configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

     // This method gets called by the runtime.
     // Use this method to add services to the container.
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         // ----- Add this DataProtection -----
         // Add a DbContext to store your Database Keys
         services.AddDbContext<MyKeysContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyKeysConnection")));

         // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
         services.AddDataProtection()
             .PersistKeysToDbContext<MyKeysContext>();

         // .... Add your services like :
         // services.AddControllersWithViews();
         // services.AddRazorPages();
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: would the keys be autodeleted when their lifetime expires?

Answer (score 7):

If you use Kubernetes and have more than one pod for your app this will most likely cause the request validation to fail because the pod that generates the RequestValidationToken is not necessarily the pod that will validate the token when POSTing back to your application. The fix should be to configure your nginx-controller or whatever ingress resource you are using and tell it to load balance so that each client uses one pod for all communication.

Update: I managed to fix it by adding the following annotations to my ingress:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/

```
Name    Description Values
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity    Sets the affinity type  string (in NGINX only cookie is possible
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name Name of the cookie that will be used    string (default to INGRESSCOOKIE)
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash Type of hash that will be used in cookie value  sha1/md5/index
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue in an area of code where I had a view calling a partial view, however, instead of returning a partial view, I was returning a view.

I changed:

*return View(index);*

to

*return PartialView(index);*

in my control and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error on .NET Core 2.1. I fixed it by adding the Data Protection service in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are calling more than one the  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`  in your view

Comment: thats what i want to do :D I have master page, and antiforgery in  master, is always out side of page, and so out side of form. and the antiforgery in page? we need to repeat it a lot, and again it may not be inside the form which lay inside your master.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when the page is old ('stale').  A refresh of the token via a page reload resolves my problem.  There seems to be some timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very interesting workaround for this problem, at least in my case.  My view was dynamically loading partial views with forms in a div using ajax, all within another form.  the master form submits no problem, and one of the partials works but the other doesn't.  The ONLY difference between the partial views was at the end of the one that was working was an empty script tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
```

I removed it and sure enough I got the error.  I added an empty script tag to the other partial view and dog gone it, it works!  I know it's not the cleanest... but as far as speed and overhead goes...

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I wanted to add another possible solution to this issue.  I ran into the same problem on an MVC application I had.  The code did not change for the better part of a year and all of the sudden we started receiving these kinds of error messages from the application.

We didn't have multiple instances of the anti-forgery token being applied to the view twice.

We had the machine key set at the global level to Autogenerate because of STIG requirements.

It was exasperating until I got part of the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207535/195350:

> If your MachineKey is set to AutoGenerate, then your verification
> tokens, etc won't survive an application restart - ASP.NET will
> generate a new key when it starts up, and then won't be able to
> decrypt the tokens correctly.

The issue was that the private memory limit of the application pool was being exceeded.  This caused a recycle and, therefore, invalidated the keys for the tokens included in the form.  Increasing the private memory limit for the application pool appears to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those getting this error on Google **AppEngine** or Google **Cloud Run**, you'll need to configure your ASP.NET Core website's Data Protection.

The documentation from the Google team is easy to follow and works.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/application-security#aspnet_core_data_protection_provider

A general overview from the Microsoft docs can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/application-security#aspnet_core_data_protection_provider

Note that you may also find you're having to login over and over, and other quirky stuff going on. This is all because Google Cloud doesn't do sticky sessions like Azure does and you're actually hitting different instances with each request.

Other errors logged, include:

```
Identity.Application was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix for this was to get the cookie and token values like this:

```
AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out var cookieToken, out var formToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may occurred when writing wrong razor form code:

wrong: `@Html.BeginForm()`

correct: `@using(Html.BeginForm())`