# how can I execute a string method in the controller in mvc5 using ajax without refreshing view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Net. Please help me. I have a void deletephoto method in my controller productmasters. The following is that method :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void DeletePhoto(ProductMaster productMaster,string id,string cid)
    {

       ProductMaster productMaster1 = (from p in db.ProductMasters
                        where p.ProductID == id && p.CompanyID == cid
                        select p).FirstOrDefault();

        string fullPath = Server.MapPath(productMaster1.ImagePathAndName);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
        }
        productMaster1.ImagePathAndName = null;
        productMaster1.Image = null;
        db.Entry(productMaster1).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In my edit view I have a remove photo link:

```
<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Remove Photo", "DeletePhoto", new { id = Model.ProductID, cid = Model.CompanyID })
</div>
```

The problem is: How can I execute the void method in this controller without refreshing the edit view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use Ajax..

Comment: That's quite easy, you need just return JSON from your controller, then you can handle controller response via javascript/jquery/angular.

Comment: I tried AJAX but its not working properly.I am not an expert in AJax so can you please send a demo code?

Comment: Your method is marked `[HttpPost]` and has `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` - a link only navigates to a GET method. You need a form, rendered with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and you need to intercepts its submit event and make an ajax call

Comment: Thank you..Gonna try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ajax.ActionLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink`

`Ajax.ActionLink` is much like the `Html.ActionLink` counterpart, it also creates the hyperlink `<a href="">Click here</a>` but when the user clicks it and has a `JavaScript` enabled browser, `Ajax.ActionLink` sends the asynchronous request instead of navigating to the new URL. With the `Ajax.ActionLink` we specify what `controller's action method` is to be invoked and also specify what to do with the response coming back from the action method.

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(
             "Remove Photo", // <-- Text to display
             "DeletePhoto", // <-- Action Method Name
             new { id = Model.ProductID, cid = Model.CompanyID },
             new AjaxOptions
             {
                 UpdateTargetId="PhotoDiv", // <-- DOM element ID to update
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
                 HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method
             })
```

**EDIT**
If you have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, you can simply use `@Ajax.BeginForm`

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("DeletePhoto", new { id = Model.ProductID, cid = Model.CompanyID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "PhotoDiv" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <input type="submit" value="Remove Photo" class="btnlink" /> // style button to look like a link by adding `btnLink` class
 }
```

**CSS**

```
.btnLink{
 background:none!important;
 border:none; 
 padding:0!important;
 font-family:arial,sans-serif; /*input has OS specific font-family*/
 color:#069;
 text-decoration:underline;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: sorry its not working,it searches for the view page and returns :Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @Lakshmi: This is good [example](https://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/partial-view-using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-5-loads-into-a-new-page/) to start with and understand the basics.

Comment: The method is a POST, not a GET (and is decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`)

Comment: Enabling `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` to true will solve that problem I suppose

Comment: @StephenMuecke: But yes, for `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, `Ajax.BeginForm` will work

Comment: I know, but your answer is `Ajax.ActionLink()` :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my answer now. Please check

Comment: It also not working..It returns an error:                                                      The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: @Lakshmi Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23402375/5619896), if it helps, because I had done the same coding earlier and it had worked.