# Authentication fails with "Unprotect ticket failed" for Asp.Net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

When I use Bearer token with an AspNetCore controller protected with `[Authorize]`, I get the log message:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[7]
      Identity.Application was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
```

I'm trying to understand what this means and what can be causing this.

The `Startup` class of the Api is has the following setup. Api uses AspNet Identity Core.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<UserAccountDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                                                                                     sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationsAssembly)));

    services.AddIdentity<UserAccount, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserAccountDbContext>();

    services.AddTransient<UserManager<UserAccount>>();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddAuthorization();

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                                             {
                                                options.Authority = _configuration.OAuth2.ServerUri;
                                                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                                                options.Audience = "api";
                                            });
        }
```

And:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The response to the caller is Unauthorized (401) without any explanation.

EDIT:

I think this has something to do with cookies as the comment suggested. I see a cookie `Identity.Application`. I cleared this and tried but didn't help. I think this may have something to do with the way my token server and the Api server are setup (both of which are using AspNet Identity).

I have one Mvc project running as the Idp on localhost:5000. Then my user manager Api which has the protected controller is hosted on localhost:5001. When I try to access the protected controller, I get redirected to the login page in the IdP project (which I think is what sets the cookie). Then I try to use the token with the controller I get the above mentioned error.

If I delete the cookies between getting the token and making the Api call, I get the following log:

```
2019-02-11 23:35:15.3711  [INFO] Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
2019-02-11 23:35:15.3711  [INFO] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
2019-02-11 23:35:15.3711  [INFO] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
```

Comment: You probably have an old cookie on the given domain, or changed something in your security configuration. Simply clear the cookies and authenticate again.

Comment: I tried clearing cookies in Postman, but I still get the error, I'm adding a bit more information. Could you please what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Postman sends Chrome's cookies as well.

Comment: I deleted all the cookies between getting the token and using it, then the request doesn't complete with the api. I added more details about the setup.

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: @ChaimEliyah See if the below works. I really can't quite remember how I resolved it. It was painful...

Comment: oh. shoot, I didn't see you were using JWT, unfortuantely I won't be able to test that for awhile. I am getting this with Cookie auth

Comment: In my case, I was sending a callback url with https while my client was configured to use http. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Facing this issue right now in my team. Apparently, using a cookie is unecessary if you use JWT. In fact, the cookie will take precedence in signalR, causing the issue (outdated cookie).

Unfortunately, I don<t have enough information to post a proper answer yet.

Comment: @chaimeliyah, did you ever figure out the issue with the cookies?

Answer (score 9):

When I spin up a development server on port 5000, I also got the "Unprotect ticket failed" error message. In Chrome I had a number of cookies lying around from another project which also ran at 5000. Deleted all cookies and error message gone.

Answer (score 2):

This can occur when you have traffic balanced across two web servers and have not configured Data Protection to share keys.

More below:

[The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402210/the-anti-forgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted/71474331#71474331)