# How to solve "An exception was thrown while deserializing the token." - error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, web-deployment

When I try to login to my web site it gives HTTP ERROR 500 error which is "An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.". My application uses identity db context..

Error:

> An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
>
> Exception:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
> antiforgery token could not be decrypted.  --->
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key
> {37d006d2-8207-4740-9e6e-5804d8840ea6} was not found in the key ring.
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[]
> protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus&
> status)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[]
> protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean&
> requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[]
> protectedData)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
> serializedToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
> serializedToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext
> httpContext)

My IdentityDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Expenses> Expenses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Revenues> Revenues { get; set; }
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;

        })
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
        services.AddAuthentication();
```

It works in my local machine, after deploying it to hosting, I cannot access the web site after successful login.. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hello. Did you check this one :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402210/the-anti-forgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted  ?

Comment: @AntiqTech yeah.. Why it works in local machine using  both remote sql and local sql server and not working after deployment? I am new to web deployment.. I have been just trying to solve this problem in a days, no clue

Comment: @Are you able to see your login page loaded or do you directly get this 500 error ? since it's specific to deployment environment, check any links/url you need to access in the back ground if there are any.

Comment: @AntiqTech  when you enter the [site](https://wallet.alishsafarli.com/), you see the loaded page. When I type incorrect user details it says its incorrect username.. when I type correct one it  redirects me to 500 error. I think there is no problem with the con string to db.. as it says it is incorrect user details.

Comment: @AntiqTech and there is no problem in local machine.. I can run it without problem in my local visual studio. I have turned on failed request tracing.. but I dunno what it say as I am new to web deployment :)

Comment: @AntiqTech the error above is given to me from hosting providers. They say that say see that error.

Comment: Check the point where you successfully determine that user/pass is valid in the backend. Maybe there is a problem with redirecting. Where do you redirect to, after successful lıogin? check the page's code.  If it has "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" like the example from that link I gave in the first post .

Comment: When I redirect to a controller/action , must it be decorated with antiforgery token ?

Comment: I only wrote that because of your exception "AntiforgeryValidationException". I don't know if you need to add that or not.  Does that controller/action  have a view ?

Comment: Yeah it does.. Do you have time to check out it with team viewer?

Comment: Add the code of that view to the end of your question. I'll see if I can spot anything out of ordinary.

Comment: Do you want a youtube video of it to see full details? so I can make a video of that.. I dont think it is about view..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228328/discussion-between-antiqtech-and-alish-safarli).