# Aspnet Core DataProtection AntiForgery Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have setup an identity system with Identity server and wanted to share the instance for tokens between 3 applications, so i have setup  the process according to this,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#entity-framework-core

```
        services.AddDbContext<DataProtectionDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(nameof(DataProtectionDbContext))));

        var certificateThumb = Configuration["CertificateConfiguration:Validation:CertificateThumbprint"];
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionDbContext>()
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificateThumb);
```

though when i add the DataProtection to the application, the anti forgery token cannot be found, iam assuming that the antiforgery tokens isn't automatically created in the data protection context.

Does anyone know why adding this causes the application to crash on the AntiForgerytoken validation?

> IdentityServer Question: is the IdentityServerBuilder.AddValidationKey
>   does that certificate concern the token validation

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206595/how-do-i-solve-an-antiforgerytoken-exception-that-occurs-after-an-iisreset-in-my) might help

Comment: @Syafiqur__ as i understand machinekey isnt a part of the new DataProtection system.

Comment: Did you set a global filter? `services.AddMvc(o => o.Filters.Add(typeof(AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute)));`

Comment: No i havent ill try that =)

Comment: Had to add the applicationname, to the dataprotector then everything works, i think the AutoValidateAntiForgeryToken, helped resolved the antiforgerytoken issue