# AntiForgery token for domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two application on IIS - A and B. I would like to submit form from application A to B. Unfortunately because of Anti-Forgery key and because cookie contains apppath in name I can't share cookie and input between two applilcation. Does anybody have some idea how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set a relevant key in your *application.config* file.

See relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577227/290343