# Html.AntiForgeryToken() breaking pagination behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

**Context**

Our web application has a feature for example "Create Employee". It shows three pages (1 of n) to allow user to enter relevant information on each page. On page 3, Save button allow user to save the employee. If user enter a incorrect value in a field on page 1 (something server can only verify) and server reports an error, the default behavior is to display page 1 with error message on top and the relevant field is mark as red.

**Problem Statement**

Above was all working until recent few build shows a breaking behavior. In above mentioned scenario, on error, the page 2 is displayed instead of page 1. Everything else is working fine like error message is correct, field on page 1 is marked red.

**Analysis**

I tried looking into pagination logic in java script, reverted back to version changes which was working. I also tried solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536739/html-antiforgerytoken-causeing-errors-after-upgrading-to-net-3-5-sp1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360078/asp-net-mvc-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed). I also cleared browser cache and reopen it.

Nothing worked.

Then I discovered major changes in UI code base was introduction of AntiForgeryToken(). I removed it from page and controller and everything worked again. I checked AntiForgeryToken() is not throwing exception.

**Question**

1. I am not sure how AntiForgeryToken() is affecting pagination code in java script?
2. What can I try to know more about the root cause?
3. Any proposed solution, remember, can not live without AntiForgeryToken()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question seems to be too localized. Repharse your question to be generic.

Comment: @Ramesh, Sorry I didn't get you. Can I request you to be more specific with details you need to understand the problem. I am happy to add more details if that helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: This question will not help people visiting this site. You are not sharing your pagination logic. You are not sure of the root cause. We can help if in a generic case. But in this case it is very localized to your logic and code.

Comment: @Ramesh - Yes you are correct, i am not sure of root cause that's why I posted here in hope someone may point me in right direction to find root cause and eventually the right solution. Do you suspect pagination logic (it is a big chunk of code) could be culprit? Then why removing AntoForgeryToken is making this problem disappear?

Comment: If your paginition logic is at client end, something should trigger it to move to page 2. I would suggest you place a breakpoint in developer tool such as chrome's / firebug and see who is invoking the script. There is no relationship between antiforgery validation of mvc and your custom logic of pagination unless your implementation does something special. The approach I mentioned above might help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else who is novice like me in Java Script/JQuery.

The pagination logic in Java Script selects a page to display based on an index calculated through Index() method of JQuery and it considers number of form elements.

Since AntiForgeryToken() adds a hidden form element the index was wrongly calculated to 1 instead of 0 (for page 1). That was the role AntiForgeryToken() was playing.

The solution is to pass pagination group identifier to Index() method so it does not consider any other element than which belongs to pagination only.

That was it.

Learning from this problem, always be more specific while finding HTML elements with JQuery or any other JS library. JQuery did provide the means but unfortunately since things was working previously the original author did not utilized the power of Index() method.